# How to fake a location (GPS) on Android phone without downloading any spoof location apps

Tags: android, location, spoofing

I really need some pointers. I've enabled "allowed mock locations" option on my android phone but I can't download apps to fake my location. I'm being monitored on what app I use or download. Downloading any spoof location apps is a big no-no for me. Anyone has any ideas how I can still spoof my location please? Any possible way?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#MockData

Comment: Is your question related to programming? Currently it seems that it should be posted somewhere else.

Comment: I agree with @Raptor42 this seems to have nothing to do  with programming...seems shady what you are doing by your description tbh. Anyway please ask on http://android.stackexchange.com/ you will get more answers and that is the more appropriate place to ask this

Comment: thousand apologies!! I will re-post my question.

Answer (score -1):

If you plug it into ADB try this, otherwise try it with an emulator.

`telnet localhost 5554`

`geo fix 1 1`